# How to rearrange continuous text with selected delimiters into columns

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching

I have a vector called `chapt1`. I want to reorganize this vector into a data frame, `df1` such that;

> 1. The integers(the ones in parenthesis) beginning each verse is printed in the first column of `df1`
> 2. The adjoining text is printed in the next column on the same row.

```
    chapt1 <- ("1. The Grand Opening (35) The black cat jumped over the 
    lazy rabbit. (36) Salt has no taste (37) The grandmaster mentors his 
    disciples   (1)   Generation of miracles.  (2)  Are we there yet: 
    opening the first stage in the dungeon.")
```

Result;

```
    35       The black cat jumped over the lazy rabbit.
    36       Salt has no taste
    37       The grandmaster mentors his disciples.
    1        Generation of miracles.
    2        Are we there yet: opening the first stage in the dungeon.
```

Note: This is just a portion of the original file.

Edit: How do I make sure that the row numbers follow the same numbering as the integers in the string.

I've tried

```
   timtim <- as_tibble(chapt3) %>%
   separate_rows(value, sep = '\\(\\b([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])\\)') %>%
   filter(row_number() > 1) %>%
   mutate(value = str_squish(value))
```

But the row numbering keeps coming out in alphabetical order. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

We may use

```
library(stringr)
trimws(str_remove(str_extract_all(chapt1, "\\(\\d+\\)[^.\\(]+")[[1]], "^\\(\\d+\\)\\s+"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another tidyverse approach:
We separate the rows with regex `'\\(\\d\\)'`, remove the first row, filter and use `str_squish` to remove spaces at beginning and end:

```
library(tidyverse)

as_tibble(chapt1) %>% 
  separate_rows(value, sep='\\(\\d\\)') %>% 
  filter(row_number() > 1) %>% 
  mutate(value = str_squish(value))
```

```
  value                                                    
  <chr>                                                    
1 The black cat jumped over the lazy rabbit.               
2 Salt has no taste                                        
3 The grandmaster mentors his disciples                    
4 Generation of miracles.                                  
5 Are we there yet: opening the first stage in the dungeon.
```